# filter and map in same iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I have this simple situation where I want to filter and map to the same value, like so:

```
 const files = results.filter(function(r){
      return r.file;
    })
    .map(function(r){
       return r.file;
    });
```

To save lines of code, as well as increase performance, I am looking for:

```
const files = results.filterAndMap(function(r){
  return r.file;
});
```

does this exist, or should I write something myself? I have wanted such functionality in a few places, just never bothered to look into it before.

Comment: What is `results`? A multidimensional array `[{file:{file:1}}, {notfile:{file:1}}]`?

Comment: results is just an array of objects: `[{},{file:x}, {}, {file:y}]`, etc.

Comment: _"results is just an array of objects: `[{},{file:x}, {}, {file:y}]`"_ Well, that array does not match context of JavaScript at Question. In that case `.map()` is not necessary. You can use `.filter()` alone to return expected result

Comment: sorry I do not follow your comment

Comment: Perhaps did not interpret Question correctly. Initially interpreted `results` as a nested array. Why is `.map()` necessary? To return an array of `[x, y]`? What is expected result?

Comment: If the requirement to use only a single `Array.prototype` method?

Answer (score 10):

**Transducers**

In its most generic form, the answer to your question lies in [transducers](https://medium.com/@drboolean/monoidal-contravariant-functors-are-actually-useful-1032211045c4). But before we go too abstract, let's see some basics first – below, we implement a couple transducers `mapReduce`, `filterReduce`, and `tapReduce`; you can add any others that you need.

```js
const mapReduce = map => reduce =>
  (acc, x) => reduce (acc, map (x))
  
const filterReduce = filter => reduce =>
  (acc, x) => filter (x) ? reduce (acc, x) : acc
  
const tapReduce = tap => reduce =>
  (acc, x) => (tap (x), reduce (acc, x))

const tcomp = (f,g) =>
  k => f (g (k))

const concat = (xs,ys) =>
  xs.concat(ys)
  
const transduce = (...ts) => xs =>
  xs.reduce (ts.reduce (tcomp, k => k) (concat), [])

const main =
  transduce (
    tapReduce (x => console.log('with:', x)),
    filterReduce (x => x.file),
    tapReduce (x => console.log('has file:', x.file)),
    mapReduce (x => x.file),
    tapReduce (x => console.log('final:', x)))
      
const data =
  [{file: 1}, {file: undefined}, {}, {file: 2}]
  
console.log (main (data))
// with: { file: 1 }
// has file: 1
// final: 1
// with: { file: undefined }
// with: {}
// with: { file: 2 }
// has file: 2
// final: 2
// => [ 1, 2 ]
```

**Chainable API**

Maybe you're satisfied with the simplicity of the code but you're unhappy with the somewhat unconventional API. If you want to preserve the ability to chain `.map`, `.filter`, `.whatever` calls without adding undue iterations, we can make a generic interface for transducing and make our chainable API on top of that – this answer is adapted from the link I shared above and [other answers I have about transducers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+transduce)

```js
// Trans Monoid
const Trans = f => ({
  runTrans: f,
  concat: ({runTrans: g}) =>
    Trans (k => f (g (k)))
})

Trans.empty = () =>
  Trans(k => k)

// transducer "primitives"
const mapper = f =>
  Trans (k => (acc, x) => k (acc, f (x)))
  
const filterer = f =>
  Trans (k => (acc, x) => f (x) ? k (acc, x) : acc)
  
const tapper = f =>
  Trans (k => (acc, x) => (f (x), k (acc, x)))
  
// chainable API
const Transduce = (t = Trans.empty()) => ({
  map: f =>
    Transduce (t.concat (mapper (f))),
  filter: f =>
    Transduce (t.concat (filterer (f))),
  tap: f =>
    Transduce (t.concat (tapper (f))),
  run: xs =>
    xs.reduce (t.runTrans ((xs,ys) => xs.concat(ys)), [])
})

// demo
const main = data =>
  Transduce()
    .tap (x => console.log('with:', x))
    .filter (x => x.file)
    .tap (x => console.log('has file:', x.file))
    .map (x => x.file)
    .tap (x => console.log('final:', x))
    .run (data)
    
const data =
  [{file: 1}, {file: undefined}, {}, {file: 2}]

console.log (main (data))
// with: { file: 1 }
// has file: 1
// final: 1
// with: { file: undefined }
// with: {}
// with: { file: 2 }
// has file: 2
// final: 2
// => [ 1, 2 ]
```

**Chainable API, take 2**

As an exercise to implement the chaining API with as little dependency ceremony as possible, I rewrote the code snippet without relying upon the `Trans` monoid implementation or the primitive transducers `mapper`, `filterer`, etc – thanks for the comment @ftor.

This is a definite downgrade in terms of overall readability. We lost that ability to just look at it and understand what was happening. We also lost the monoid interface which made it easy for us to reason about our transducers in other expressions. A big gain here tho is the definition of `Transduce` is contained within 10 lines of source code; compared to 28 before – so while the expressions are more complex, you can probably finish reading the entire definition before your brain starts struggling

```js
// chainable API only (no external dependencies)
const Transduce = (t = k => k) => ({
  map: f =>
    Transduce (k => t ((acc, x) => k (acc, f (x)))),
  filter: f =>
    Transduce (k => t ((acc, x) => f (x) ? k (acc, x) : acc)),
  tap: f =>
    Transduce (k => t ((acc, x) => (f (x), k (acc, x)))),
  run: xs =>
    xs.reduce (t ((xs,ys) => xs.concat(ys)), [])
})

// demo (this stays the same)
const main = data =>
  Transduce()
    .tap (x => console.log('with:', x))
    .filter (x => x.file)
    .tap (x => console.log('has file:', x.file))
    .map (x => x.file)
    .tap (x => console.log('final:', x))
    .run (data)
    
const data =
  [{file: 1}, {file: undefined}, {}, {file: 2}]

console.log (main (data))
// with: { file: 1 }
// has file: 1
// final: 1
// with: { file: undefined }
// with: {}
// with: { file: 2 }
// has file: 2
// final: 2
// => [ 1, 2 ]
```

**> Talks about performance**

When it comes to speed, no functional variant of this is ever going to beat a static `for` loop which combines all of your program statements in a single loop body. However, the transducers above do have the *potential* to be faster than a series of `.map`/`.filter`/`.whatever` calls where multiple iterations thru a large data set would be expensive.

**Coding style & implementation**

The very essence of the transducer lies in `mapReduce`, which is why I chose to introduce it first. If you can understand how to take multiple `mapReduce` calls and sequence them together, you'll understand transducers.

Of course you can implement transducers in any number of ways, but I found [Brian's approach](https://medium.com/@drboolean/monoidal-contravariant-functors-are-actually-useful-1032211045c4) the most useful as it encodes transducers as a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) – having a monoid allows us make all sorts of convenient assumptions about it. And once we transduce an Array (one type of monoid), you might wonder how you can transduce any other monoid... in such a case, get reading that article!

Comment: Looks fun, will investigate :)

Comment: Brain talks about contravariant functors and combines them with boolean monoids under conjunction to create composable predicates. You actually finished his blog post by implementing a monoidal transducer - I am not sure if your composition is contravariant though. Anyway, brilliant work (if one likes method chaining - which I do not :D I'll try to simplify it in the next days, if such an undertaking is possible at all.

Comment: This answer boosted my Javascript IQ by 30 or more points. Wow!

Answer (score 9):

If you really need to do it in 1 function, you'll need to use `reduce` like this

```
results.reduce(
  // add the file name to accumulator if it exists
  (acc, result) => result.file ? acc.concat([result.file]) : acc,
  // pass empty array for initial accumulator value
  []
)
```

And if you need to squeeze more performance you can change `concat` to `push` and return the original accumulator array to avoid creating extra arrays.

However, the fastest solution is probably a good old `for` loop which avoids all the function calls and stack frames

```
files = []
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  var file = results[i].file
  if (file) files.push(file)
}
```

But I think `filter/map` approach is much more expressive and readable

Answer (score 3):

To increase performance you have to measure what solution will be faster. Let's play for a moment https://jsperf.com/filter-than-map-or-reduce/1

Any other test cases are welcome.

[image]

If you want to play with benchmark against NodeJS (remember to `npm i benchmark`)

```
var suite = new (require('benchmark')).Suite

function getSampleInput() {
  return [{file: 'foo'}, {other: 'bar'}, {file: 'baz'}, {file: 'quux'}, {other: 'quuxdoo'}, {file: 'foobar'}, {file: 'foo'}, {other: 'bar'}, {file: 'baz'}, {file: 'quux'}, {other: 'quuxdoo'}, {file: 'foobar'}, {file: 'foo'}, {other: 'bar'}, {file: 'baz'}, {file: 'quux'}, {other: 'quuxdoo'}, {file: 'foobar'}, {file: 'foo'}, {other: 'bar'}, {file: 'baz'}, {file: 'quux'}, {other: 'quuxdoo'}, {file: 'foobar'}, {file: 'foo'}, {other: 'bar'}, {file: 'baz'}, {file: 'quux'}, {other: 'quuxdoo'}, {file: 'foobar'}, {file: 'foo'}, {other: 'bar'}, {file: 'baz'}, {file: 'quux'}, {other: 'quuxdoo'}, {file: 'foobar'}, {file: 'foo'}, {other: 'bar'}, {file: 'baz'}, {file: 'quux'}, {other: 'quuxdoo'}, {file: 'foobar'}, {file: 'foo'}, {other: 'bar'}, {file: 'baz'}, {file: 'quux'}, {other: 'quuxdoo'}, {file: 'foobar'}]
}

// author https://stackoverflow.com/users/3716153/gaafar 
function reduce(results) {
  return results.reduce(
    (acc, result) => result.file ? acc.concat([result.file]) : acc ,
    []
  )  
}

// author https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223975/alexander-mills
function filterThanMap(results) {
  return results.filter(function(r){
    return r.file;
  })
  .map(function(r){
     return r.file;
  });
}

// author https://stackoverflow.com/users/5361130/ponury-kostek
function forEach(results) {
  const files = [];

  results.forEach(function(r){
    if(r.file) files.push(r.file); 
  });

  return files
}

suite
  .add('filterThanMap', function() {filterThanMap(getSampleInput())})
  .add('reduce', function() {reduce(getSampleInput())})
  .add('forEach', function() {forEach(getSampleInput())})
  .on('complete', function() {
    console.log('results:')
    this.forEach(function(result) {
      console.log(result.name, result.count, result.times.elapsed)
    })
    console.log('the fastest is', this.filter('fastest').map('name')[0])
  })
  .run()
```

Comment: Can you add forEach to comparison?

Comment: @ponury-kostek here you are https://jsperf.com/filter-than-map-or-reduce/1 - looks like forEach is the most fastest in that challenge

Comment: Thx. I know, that's why I'm surprised they try to do this in some  strange ways.

Comment: I'm guessing the performance issue with the `reduce` option isn't really in the fact that it uses `reduce`, it's in that it uses `concat`... I often end up using `(acc.push(x), acc)` instead of `acc.concat(x)`. It mutates the `acc` array, but since the array is created inside your function, it shouldn't be too big of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `forEach`?

```js
const files = [];
results.forEach(function(r){
  if(r.file) {
    files.push(r.file);  
  }
});
```

If this is not fast enough you can use `fast.js` and make some other micro optimizations

```js
const files = [];
const length = results.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  if (results[i].file) {
    files[files.length] = results[i].file;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the value of `o.file` or concat with an empty array for the result.

```
results.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(o.file || []), []);
```

Comment: das ist a lot of concatenations

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
const results = [{file:{file:1}}, {notfile:{file:1}}];

const files = results.reduce(function(arr, r){
                return r.file ? arr = [...arr, r.file.file] : arr;
              }, []);
              
console.log(files); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are [iterable](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_iterables.asp) objects, and we can apply all needed operations in just one iteration.

Example below does such single iteration, using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipe, filter, map} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipe(
    results,
    filter(r => !!r.file),
    map(m => m.file)
);

console.log('files:', [...i]);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   const file = (array) => {
     return array.reduce((acc,curr) => curr.file ? acc.concat(curr) : acc, 
     [])
    }
```

Process :

acc initiate as [ ] (empty array) . [reduce docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: `reduce` is the most expensive operation than cheapest one - as https://jsperf.com/filter-than-map-or-reduce/1 proofs it

Comment: Comparing filter-then-map to reduce, at least in the screenshot provided in your answer, @KrzysztofSafjanowski, shows a very minor difference between the two.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski wow my apologies reduce is more expensive thanks for mention me . thanks for mention me, I was thinking  reduce is cheaper  .

Comment: @ajilantang wait a couple of more v8 iterations and it probably won't be. Logically, `reduce` *should* be cheaper as you're only iterating the array once. I would guess that one or both of two things is happening: the JIT is optimizing away one of the passes in the `map/filter` case and/or is optimizing away the creation of the intermediate data structures and generating less garbage.